# Under what condition do the limits of the functions defined below exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I have a system of autonomous differential equations:

$$\mathbf{\dot{x}}={{\mathbf{S}}^{T}}\mathbf{f}\left( \mathbf{x} \right)$$
where

$\mathbf{x}:\left[ 0,\infty  \right)\to {{\left[ 0,\infty  \right)}^{n}}$ is a continuously differentiable function,

$\mathbf{f}:{{\left[ 0,\infty  \right)}^{n}}\to {{\left[ 0,\infty  \right)}^{m}}$ is a locally Lipschitz continuous function,

$\mathbf{S}\in {{\left( -\infty ,\infty  \right)}^{m\times n}}$ is a matrix for which $\mathbf{S\eta }={{\mathbf{0}}_{m}}$ is in force, where $\mathbf{\eta }\in {{\left( 0,\infty  \right)}^{n}}$ is a strictly positive vector.

I would like to ask what type of condition should be necessary (and sufficient) to the existence of the strictly positive limit $\underset{t\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\mathbf{x}\left( t \right)$ in respect of the function $\mathbf{f}$?

(In another post it was proved that $\mathbf{x}$ is bounded.)

Comment: Any limiting point $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ must satisfy $S^Tf(a)=0$. Conversely, if $S^Tf(a)=0$ for a particular vector $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then we can choose  $x(0)=a$ and we indeed get $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} x(t)=a$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question connected to this one. What is the condition of a unique limit point?

Comment: We need the equation $S^Tf(x)=0$ to have a unique solution $x=a$.